# how do I Iterate through selector list while using Itemloaders in scrapy? details in description

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a list of countries and their details that are members of UN. Here is my approach **without using Item Loaders**

Here, I am getting a parent tag that **contains** the details of  **all the UN members** like name, date of joining, website, phone number and UN headquarters. Not all countries have a website, phone no and child details.
I am running a loop through the parent tag and extracting the details one by one and storing it in a variable then I am assigning tha variable to items.

```
import scrapy
from learn_scrapy.items import UNMemberItem

class UNMemberDetails(scrapy.Spider):
    name  = 'UN_details'
    start_urls = ['http://www.un.org/en/member-states/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        Get the details of the UN members
        """
        members_tag = response.css('div.member-state.col-md-12')
        #item_list = []
        for member  in members_tag:
            member_name = member.css('span.member-state-name::text').extract()
            member_join_date = member.css('span.date-display-single::text').extract()
            member_website = member.css('div.site >  a::text').extract()
            member_phone = member.css('div.phone > ul > li::text').extract()
            member_address = member.css('div.mail >  a::text').extract()
            member_national_holiday = member.css('div.national-holiday::text').extract()
            UN_member = UNMemberItem()
            UN_member['country_name'] = member_name
            UN_member['join_date'] = member_join_date
            if len(member_website) == 0:
                member_website ='NA'
            UN_member['website'] = member_website
            if len(member_phone) == 0:
                    member_phone = 'NA'
            UN_member['phone'] = member_phone
            if len(member_address) == 0:
                member_address = 'NA'
            UN_member['mail_address'] = member_address
            UN_member['national_holiday'] = member_national_holiday
            print (UN_member)
            UN_member = str(UN_member)
            #item_list.append(UN_members)
            with open('un_members_list.txt','a') as f:
                    f.write(UN_member + "\n")
```

And this my progress. I get a whole list of countries in an item. I want a single country in the item. What should be my aproach in this case?

```
import scrapy

from learn_scrapy.items import UNMemberItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class UNMemberDetails(scrapy.Spider):
    name  = 'UN_details_loader'
    start_urls = ['http://www.un.org/en/member-states/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        item_loader_object = ItemLoader(UNMemberItem(), response=response)
        nested_loader  =  item_loader_object.nested_css('div.member-state.col-md-12')
        nested_loader.add_css('country_name', 'span.member-state-name::text')
        nested_loader.add_css('join_date', 'span.date-display-single::text')
        nested_loader.add_css('website', 'div.site >  a::text')
        nested_loader.add_css('phone','div.phone > ul > li::text')
        nested_loader.add_css('mail_address','div.mail > a::text')
        nested_loader.add_css('national_holiday','div.national-holiday::text')
```

Comment: Why not output a JSONLines file using `scrapy crawl yourSpider -o yourFile.jl` ... I see you are saving a JSON object on each line in your code, so just use scrapy's JSONLines feed exporters

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use item loaders for an assignment.

Comment: Do `scrapy crawl yourSpider -o yourFile.jl` and then just do `yield nested_loader` where you have the entire item.

Comment: Found the solution and answered it.

Answer (score 1):

After some Research, I found the solution.

**Instead of this**

```
def parse(self, response):
        item_loader_object = ItemLoader(UNMemberItem(), response=response)
```

You have will have to specify the **selector** parameter in the method. That means your ItemLoader will extract the Items from specified **'selector'** instead of whole **response** (whole web page).

It is like selecting a part of a page from the whole response (page) and then selecting your items from it and plus you are iterating through it.

```
def parse(self, response):
            item_loader_object = ItemLoader(UNMemberItem(), selector=member_tag)
```

**And the new code would like something like this**

```
members_tag  =  response.css('div.member-state.col-md-12')
for member  in members_tag:
      item_loader_object = ItemLoader(UNMemberItem(), response=member)
      item_loader.add_css('country_name','span.member-state-name::text')
      item_loader.add_css('join_date','span.date-display-single::text')
      item_loader.add_css('website', 'div.site >  a::text')
      item_loader.add_css('phone','div.phone > ul > li::text')
      item_loader.add_css('mail_address','div.mail > a::text')
      item_loader.add_css('national_holiday','div.national-holiday::text')
```

The code is much is cleaner than very first code snippet in the question and gets the job done.